# UIBarButtonItem on UINavigationBar not responding on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appstore-approval, iphone-5

I have a problem - my app got rejected 3 times for the same reason, "Selecting the Action button does not produce an action". Apple said the "share button" isn't working as well.
On my devices (ipod 4 + ipod 5) and the iphone simulation, the share button works, and opens an action sheet view with 3 options to choose from, and they all work fine.

The share button is a UIBarButtonItem and stand on the UINavigationBar.
the back button and the star button work great, but still the share button is not responding and doesn't produce any action.

[image] 
This is my app screenshot.

This is my button code:

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 33, 22);
    [rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_share.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_shareSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(share) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=rightItem;
```

What can I do? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What are the iOS versions you are testing on? Is there by any chance a UITapGestureRecognizer associated with the Navigation Bar?

Comment: What about iOS 5 compatibility? Did you try compiling on the iOS5.0 simulator?

Comment: Also - please post the code that handles the "share" action. It's important in order to understand how you're displaying the UIActionSheet.

Comment: Hi Sigalit, my app got rejected for the same reason. Could you please let me know how you fixed the issue??

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce the problem yourself? It would be a good start.

I think you may be having a problem because you're adding a target to the `UIButton` custom view and not the actual bar button item.

So please try setting the action and target properties on the `UIbarButtonItem` itself. Be sure to remove the `rightButton addTarget` line.

If that doesn't work, I'd then try not using a `UIbutton` for the custom view.

**Btw, why aren't you just using `UIBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem:`?** i think the "action" style will give you the look you want, with less hassle.

Comment: I don't agree - the action defined by the UIButton should be called in this scenario

Comment: I'm suggesting he use the less complex and more obvious setup.

Comment: I agree that simple is better, but there aren't a lot of simple ways to define a custom bar button item - in her case, they have designed a special button graphic and they want to use it.

Comment: IKWYM, but it looks like an action button to me!